# Populate select menu with options from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having issues populating my select menu with options from array using this approach

```
var adultAgesArr = ['18 - 20', '21 - 30', '31 - 40', '41 - 50', '51 - 60', '60 +'];
var $ageOptions = '';
$.each(adultAgesArr, function(index, value){
    $ageOptions += $('<option/>', {text: value});
})
```

and after

```
$('<select/>').append($ageOptions)
```

what I get as a result is

```
<select>
[Object object] [Object object] [Object object] [Object object] [Object object] [Object object]
</select>
```

Comment: I believe, that by doing this: $ageOptions += $('<option/>', {text: value}); - you're trying to concatenate string (which is initially evaluates to '') and then whatever you have ($('<option/>', {text: value});). By using operator += it is converted to a string. If an ordinary native object is converted to a string, it first uses toString() method, then it tries valueOf method (if toString() doesn't return a primitive which can be converted to a String()

I would check what $('<option/>', {text: value}); returns inside of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$select = $('select');
$.each(adultAgesArr, function(index, value){
  $select.append($('<option/>', {text: value, value: value}));
})
```

Before it appeared that you were coercing the jQuery objects to a string. I think this way, if you cache `select` beforehand, is just as efficient.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6vmprjj1/3/)

Comment: But it is not giving any values to the options. Only setting the display text. How do we do that.  I used .outerHTML to get HTML from object. http://jsfiddle.net/80jh2ktw/

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
<select id="menu"></select>

var populate = function() {
    var adultAgesArr = ['18 - 20', '21 - 30', '31 - 40', '41 - 50', '51 - 60', '60 +'],
    select = $('#menu')[0];

    $.each(adultAgesArr, function(index, value){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = value;
        opt.innerHTML = value;
        select.appendChild(opt);
    });
}

populate();
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating an option instead of doing this:

```
 $ageOptions += $("< option/>", {text: value});
```

Is better to do this:

```
 new Option("option text", "value")
```

then append.